# Implement a Simple Authorization Function in ASP.NET Without Using ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, authorization, asp.net-identity

I'm building a simple CMS using ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6. I have 2 sites: Public and Admin. Public site to diplay all the content and Admin site to manage all the content.

I only need a single Admin account to handle all the content in the Admin site. 
I'm thinking to use a session to keep the logged in user data and check for the session details when accessing an authorized page.

Keep the user data in a session.

```
var obj = db.UserProfiles.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(objUser.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();  
if (obj != null)  
{  
   Session["UserID"] = obj.UserId.ToString();  
   Session["UserName"] = obj.UserName.ToString();  
   return RedirectToAction("UserDashBoard");  
}
```

Check before accessing an authorized page.

```
public ActionResult UserDashBoard()  
{  
     if (Session["UserID"] != null)  
     {  
         return View();  
     } else  
     {  
         return RedirectToAction("Login");  
     }  
 }
```

So with this approach I wouldn't need to implement advance ASP Identity functions for the authorization.

Is this approach correct and  would there be any downsides using this approach?

Comment: Well firstly it seems you may be storing passwords in plain text which would be a major flaw in rolling your own authorisation. But yes, upon login storing in the session a flag that the user is logged in, and then checking that flag for pages that require authorisation is correct.

Comment: @xcvd Thanks. I'll be using a hashing function to save the password. This was just a sample code. Are there any downsides of this approach comparing to ASP identity?

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: About "sample code": It becomes production code all to often so it is best to make sample code secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER use session for authentication.  It's insecure for starters, and it won't survive a loss of session (which IIS can kill at any time, for any reason).  Session cookies are not encrypted, so they can be grabbed and used easily (assuming a non-encrypted link, even if you use HTTPS for authentication pages).

Another issue is that you are doing your authentication way too late in the pipeline.  OnAuthenticate runs at the very beginning of the pipeline, while you action methods are towards the end.  This means that the site is doing a lot of work it doesn't have to do if the user is not authorized.

I'm not sure why you are so against using Identity, the MVC basic templates already roll a full identity implementation for you.  You don't have to do much.

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful. I'm not against Identity at all. My concern was since I'm having a 1 user type (Admin), 'AspNetRoles', 'AspNetUserRoles', 'AspNetUserClaims' tables won't be required. I'm concerned that using ASP Identity is too much or not required in my scenario.

Comment: @AkiT - It's better to use a well written, debugged, and exapandable component that may do too much than to roll your own security and do too little.  At least in my opinion.  Most people who roll their own security do so poorly, and insecurely.  Because you're not an expert on security.  Also, what happens when you decide you want users to be able to log-in so they can personalize their experience, or some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

The downside is that you have to write it all yourself anyway. You already need role-based authorisation and have to write cludges. Identity already have this implemented and tested for you. Also keeping information in session is not very secure.

And you don't need to implement much yourself anyway. Yes, there are lot of functionality that you'll probably won't need, but just don't use it.

Don't build your own authorisation system. Since you ask this question, you are probably not qualified enough to make it secure.